# "Roll a 40 down the street" meaning

Tags: slang, jokes

I have stumbled across the following joke in the Fallout 4 video game:

> What is the best way to start a parade in South Boston?
> Roll a 40 down the street.

I have no idea what *roll a 40 down the street* means. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "40" is a 40 ounce bottle of beer or malt liquor (usually malt liquor)

> The phrase "40 ounce" typically refers to a single glass bottle of malt liquor, a form of beer noted for its high alcohol content by volume. ([Source](https://www.reference.com/food/many-beers-equal-40-ounce-c9c18e7dc76d16c0))

Large bottles of malt liquor are inexpensive and associated with heavy drinkers that don't have a lot of money. The "joke" is disparaging the people who live in South Boston as the type of people who would chase a bottle of cheap liquor rolling down the street.

Comment: Wow... I would have never deciphered that on my own. Thank you.

Comment: @PavelHoral I would give you some usage examples, but a lot of the examples I could find were pretty vulgar stuff. If you want to look for yourself, "40" is usually spelled out, so you would search for "a forty"...